# How to use VBA to clear content?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have all cells empty after opening my spreadsheet on "ThisWorkbook".

Code:

```
Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi").Range("C19") = ""
```

and

```
Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi").Liste_cible.Clear
Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi").Liste_cible.Value = ""
```

But it takes a little time before deleting, so I can see the data after opening (1-2 seconds) and it is deleted after.

Maybe you know some efficient function VBA that deletes the data while opening the spreadsheet ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Consider clearing it on WorkbookClose?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thnk you for the idea! I must write the code in  "ThisWorkbook" ? Or in another location. The code is like : Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi").Range("C19") = ""
End Sub

Comment: @Ron Rosenfed That's an interesting approach, how would you do it?

Comment: AFAIK, the only place you can put it is in the `ThisWorkbook` module.  I'm not familiar with .`Liste_cible` property though, as my VBA only works in English.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you, that works. It is better to write this code on the beginning or on the end of ThisWorkbook module please ?

Comment: I don't know that it makes any difference.  You'd have to do some testing if you think it does.

Comment: @Gass Read about event-triggered macros in Excel.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I will thanks.